# Question about Big O notation for asymptotic behavior in convergent power series

Tags: asymptotics, power-series

Examples of such use of Big O notation can be found for instance on Wolfram Alpha [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20series%20of%20e%5Ex). More details on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinite_asymptotics).

The idea, as I understand it, is that the term between parenthesis in Big O bounds the rest of the series asymptotically (as $x$ goes to zero or infinity) giving and elegant way of writing the series (if you don't like "$+ \dots$" or "etc") while also providing an error approximation. Taking the example of $e^x$:

$$
e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+O(x^5)
$$

When we write $O(x^5)$ we mean that all the rest of the terms (like $(x^6)/6!+(x^7)/7!+(x^8)/8!+\dots$) are bounded by $x^5$ as $x$ goes to $0$. Giving a more concrete example if we take $e^2.42$ then this is more or less $1 + 2.42 + (1/2)(2.42)^2 + (1/6)(2.42)^3 + (1/24)(2.42)^4$ and the error between the approximation and the actual value is no larger than $2.42^5$.

The question is **how do we know this**?

Certainly $x^5$ bounds, as $x$ goes to $0$, each term individually ($Cx^n=O(x^5)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ as long as $n>5$, $C$ constant) but how do we prove the **sum** of all the individual terms is bounded? We have to show that:

$$
O(x^5)=\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}+\frac{x^{10}}{10!}+\frac{x^{11}}{11!}+...),x\rightarrow 0
$$

Falling back on the previous example, maybe the infinite sum will actually be slightly larger than $2.42^5$. How do we prove this is actually not the case? While I have used the example of $e^x$, feel free to give a more general proof, and not one for this particular function only.

Your help with this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to read this and have a good day.

Comment: While your question is legitimate, it sure is not a question fit for this website and will soon be closed. You should try another site, like MathStackExchange.

Comment: My bad :( Will it get transferred automatically or shall I make a new post on stackexchange?

Comment: @Zav: do not worry, this will happen more or less automatically. This is a nice question.